# Redis Cli Not Working in Laravel 8 after installing it

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-8

I just installed Laravel 8 on Windows 10 and ran this command for installing Redis:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Then at the Terminal, I tried `redis-cli` but not working somehow and says:

**'redis-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Here is my `config/database.php`:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: [`Refer docs`](https://github.com/predis/predis/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: Didn't you post this exact question like an hour or so ago (which now seems to have been deleted)?

Comment: predis is a package that can connect to a redis server. redis-cli is another package that can connect to a redis server and typically gets installed when you install the redis server software. Installing predis does not mean you're installing a redis server or redis cli.

Comment: @nice_dev I have added my config/database.php, I don't know how to call it now